# Why do I receive this error in an angular request? (CORS)

Tags: angular, api, request, cors

I have this Controller

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  url: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){
    this.url = 'https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayerbiostats?PerMode=Totals&LeagueID=00&Season=2017-18&SeasonType=Regular Season';

    this.http.get(this.url,)
      .subscribe(/*data => {*/
        data => {
          console.log("HOLA");
        },
        err => {
          console.log("Error occured.")
    });
  }
}
```

It's a request to NBA API Stats, if I execute in Postman I see all data, but if I execute with Angular 4 I see the next error in Chrome Developer Tools

> Failed to load
>   https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayerbiostats?PerMode=Totals&LeagueID=00&Season=2017-18&SeasonType=Regular%20Season:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I'm running the server with the command `ng serve`

I have tried many solutions that I have read online, but I think that the only solution is to make the change in the backend

Comment: Yes, you already asked this question before, and you already had a response.

Comment: pretty much as the error says the server does not set a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.

Comment: in case you were wondering why does it fail unlike postman, see this issue: https://github.com/bttmly/nba/issues/34

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to configure server for work with CORS from your site.

And why Postman works correctly? Because it is not a browser. You completely controls whole request by Postman.

But when you works with browser it uses some specific methods to avoid some attacks like CSRF.